# Problem with SELECT INTO using local variables

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql5

I need to create an SQL query to insert some data into a table based on the results of a SELECT query into a local variable.  My DB platform is MySQL 5.1, but I don't think that should make a difference here.  Basically, what I want to do is:

```
SELECT id INTO var_name FROM table1 WHERE some_column='something' LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO table2 (`number`) VALUES (@var_name);
```

I can't get past the first statement, though, as I get the error "Undeclared variable var_name".  I've also tried putting the statement in a BEGIN/END block, and a stored procedure, but then I encounter other errors which state only that there is an error on the SELECT line.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
INSERT INTO table2 (`number`)
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE some_column='something' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Ah - beat me to it - very nice!

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `@var_name` and then select into `@var_name`.  I don't know MySQL too well but try something like this:

```
declare @var_name varchar(100);
SELECT id INTO @var_name FROM table1 WHERE some_column='something' LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO table2 (`number`) VALUES (@var_name);
```

#### Edit: Perhaps a better way to do it:

```
insert into table2 ('number')
select id 
from table1 
where some_column = 'something' LIMIT 1;
```

This negates the need for a variable and will be a lot faster and easier to understand down the road.

Comment: Why should he even use a variable at all?

Comment: When I tried this, I get an error saying "Undeclared variable: id".  Also when I try surrounding it with backticks `id`.  Why is this?

Comment: Good point - I don't think he does for this example but he did ask how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I didn't need a variable, it turns out.  Sorry; I marked the other answer as correct, as it's the better solution here. :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the SELECT INTO syntax a bit. It is for storing the results in a new table.

Comment: Ah yes - I am used to T-SQL :)

Comment: So am I. Actually my comment was meant to be for sqook. But since you never know with MySQL, maybe you can use the syntax to fill variables there. In T-SQL, you would do "SELECT @var = column FROM table"

Answer (score -2):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name
AS  
SELECT ...(your select)
```

Comment: This assumes the table hasn't been created yet, which the OP didn't mention.